# common sql where in inner join

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm pretty new to SQL database world. I have a requirement where I have to store each change made to the table row(i.e update, delete) in that table as versions. I can fetch latest version(i.e latest changes with `isLatest`, `isDeleted` flags. Now, I need to join atleast 3 tables( it may increase upto 20 tables overtime if it is scary). So the join should be applied to the latest documents i.e `isLatest=true` and it is not deleted i.e `isDeleted=false`. is there any way to use common sql where at the end of query because all the tables have that `isLatest`and `IsDeleted` rows.
here's my tables structure and expected output.

User Table:

```
| id | name   | version | isLatest | isDeleted |
| 1  | John   | 0       | false    | false     |
| 1  | john   | 1       | false    | false     |
| 1  | Johnny | 2       | true     | false     |
| 2  | Sarah  | 2       | true     | false     |
| 2  | sarah  | 1       | false    | false     |
| 2  | Sarah  | 0       | false    | false     |
| 3  | Jane   | 1       | true     | true      |
| 3  | Jane   | 0       | false    | true      |
```

Employment Table:

```
| user_id | employment_id | type      | isLatest | isDeleted |   |
| 1       | emp1          | Intern    | false    | false     |   |
| 1       | emp1          | Part Time | false    | false     |   |
| 1       | emp1          | Full Time | true     | false     |   |
| 2       | emp2          | Full Time | false    | false     |   |
| 2       | emp2          | Part Time | true     | false     |   |
| 3       | emp3          | Part Time | true     | true      |   |
```

Expected Output:

```
| user_id | name  | employment_id | type      | isLatest | isDeleted |
| 1       | Johnny| emp1          | Full Time | true     | false     |
| 2       | Sarah | emp2          | Part Time | true     | false     |
```

Query I wanted to use:

```sql
select employment.user_id, user.id, employment.employment_id, 
        employment.type, user.isLatest, user.isDeleted 
from employment 
    inner join user ON user.id = employment.user_id 
where isLatest = true and isDeleted = false
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but just a general FYI - there a few problems with this approach (assuming you're not leaving out any information). One - it's not following 3NF (deleted and latest version is data that is unique to id), two - there's no primary key - you can derive a primary key from (user_id, version) but it can potentially be a bigger headache. Three - Regardless of which approach you take, make sure you have indexes in line with your queries or forget 20 tables, going to have a headache with 3 :)

Comment: Yes. I've used id and version as the composite primary key

Answer (score 0):

You would basically use a `join` and filter for the rows you want:

```sql
select . . .    -- whatever columns you want
from users u join
     employment e
     on u.user_id = e.user_id
where u.isLatest and e.isLatest and
      not u.isDeleted and not e.isDeleted;
```

Note:  If the flags are numbers, then you can use them without comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I wanted to generate queries dynamically. instead of writing ```u.isLatest``` and ```e.isLatest``` on every line, I just wanted use it at then end of query(since I mentioned that I will be joining more than 3 tables). it may not be effective to use that on every line.can we name alias to whole query and use filtering at the end with alias?

Comment: @ajay . . . I don't understand.  This *is* filtering "at the end" in a sense -- in the `where` clause after you `join`.  Perhaps what you really want are views are return only the undeleted latest row.